# Row values check in consecutive rows using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set as below. I want to check the row values consecutive in L/P column one by one .

As an example for the `tradedate` between 2019-02-12 and 2019-02-14 **L/P** return values were 1 0 0. for that same pattern there were records for  `tradedate` between 2019-02-16 and 2019-02-18.

How do I check that same pattern in L/P column using SQL Server?

```
tradedate   price   lost / profit   L/P
----------  -----   ------------   ----
2019-02-11  150.00   0.00            1
2019-02-12  330.00   180.00          1
2019-02-13  329.00   -1.00           0
2019-02-14  151.00   -178.00         0
2019-02-15  148.00   -3.00           0
2019-02-16  329.00   181.00          1
2019-02-17  326.00   -3.00           0
2019-02-18  146.00   -180.00         0
```

The DDL statement for table creation

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ticker
(
     symbol    VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
     tradedate DATE           NOT NULL,
     price     NUMERIC(12, 2) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT PK_Ticker
         PRIMARY KEY (symbol, tradedate)
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Ticker(symbol, tradedate, price) 
VALUES
  ('STOCK1', '20190211', 150.00),
  ('STOCK1', '20190212', 330.00), 
  ('STOCK1', '20190213', 329.00),  
  ('STOCK1', '20190214', 151.00),  
  ('STOCK1', '20190215', 148.00),  
  ('STOCK1', '20190216', 329.00),  
  ('STOCK1', '20190217', 326.00),  
  ('STOCK1', '20190218', 146.00);
```

SQL query for getting above data set

`````
SELECT  
    tradedate,
    price,
    ((LAG(price, 1, price) OVER (ORDER BY tradedate)) - price) * -1 AS 'lost / profit',
    CASE WHEN ((LAG(price, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY tradedate)) - price) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'L / P'
FROM    
    Ticker t
WHERE   
    tradedate BETWEEN '2019-02-11' AND '2019-02-18'
````
`````

Comment: Please include table DDL, sample data insert scripts, and desired results.

Comment: So what are your expected results?

Comment: I want Tradedate column as output. for tradedate between 2019-02-16 and 2019-02-18 for that exact pattern 1,0 and 0. which L/P column have Tradedate for  2019-02-12 and 2019-02-14

Comment: I don't understand.  Please add the desired results as a table to your question.

Comment: ``2019-02-12  330.00   180.00          1
2019-02-13  329.00   -1.00             0
2019-02-14  151.00   -178.00         0  `` this is output for Tradedate for 2019-02-12 and 2019-02-14 by using above query. L/P column output is 1, 0 and 0. for that exact pattern (1,0,0) there is another date range  2019-02-16 and 2019-02-18. I want to know how do I get the date range by matching exact raw pattern (1,0,0)

Comment: No one can read tabular data out of your comments.  Please put it in the question, formatted so we can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a aggregate function like  `STRING_AGG()`:

(**UPDATED**):

```
SELECT 
     STRING_AGG([L / P], ' ') 
FROM
(SELECT tradedate
            ,price 
            ,((LAG(price, 1, price) OVER (ORDER BY tradedate)) - price) * -1 AS 'lost / profit'
            ,CASE WHEN ((LAG(price, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY tradedate)) - price) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'L / P'
    FROM    Ticker t
    WHERE   tradedate BETWEEN '2019-02-12' AND '2019-02-14')
EXCEPT
SELECT 
     STRING_AGG([L / P], ' ') 
FROM
(SELECT tradedate
            ,price 
            ,((LAG(price, 1, price) OVER (ORDER BY tradedate)) - price) * -1 AS 'lost / profit'
            ,CASE WHEN ((LAG(price, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY tradedate)) - price) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'L / P'
    FROM    Ticker t
    WHERE   tradedate BETWEEN '2019-02-16' AND '2019-02-18')
```

Comment: I have updated the question. My question is for the date range tradedate between 2019-02-12 and 2019-02-14  L/P column return values were 1, 0 and  0. for that same pattern in L/P column which means 1,0 and 0 there were records for tradedate between 2019-02-16 and 2019-02-18. how do I get those date range in SQL